# "Exception occurred while test discoverer was loading tests"

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm writing a desktop Windows 8 application, and always get this error when building the project:

> An exception occurred while test discoverer 'MSAppContainerTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm using the C++ unit test framework that's built into Visual Studio 2012, and the error doesn't seem to impact my builds or test runs. I haven't found anything about this online; any ideas what causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Post a build, it seems VS triggers all installed test-adapters (MSTest, et.all) into a discovery phase where they attempt to refresh the list of tests. If during this process, an exception occurs, the above generic error message is shown.

I faced this with NUnit - but you seem to be having the same with MSAppContainer. I'm not sure what that is. It won't affect your builds but may cause tests to be not found.

The NUnit adapter has been modified to log detailed information to the Output window (Tests) in case of a failure. For MSTest, I think [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/03/02/how-to-enable-ute-logs.aspx) should help uncover more details

Comment: I've looked at this a bit, but I haven't been able to get any traces for the components that link points to. I'll poke around a bit more; maybe the runner that's used for the C++ testing has a different home.